# replace word in string without replacing duplicates

Tags: string, replace, lua, roblox

I want to do something like `('hello i am hello i is'):gsub('hello', 'hola')` without making the string `'hola i am hola i is'` but instead `'hello i am hola i is'`.

I have no clue how to approach this issue since it probably requires complex string manipulation, and I'm only a 4/10 when it comes to string manipulation.

two of the things I want to avoid are using `string.sub` and `for loops`, but if I'm required to use them then I can.

please help me with my issue

Comment: you need to provide more info on the possible strings. otherwise the solutino is simply to replace `" hello"` with `" hola"` as the first one you don't want to replace has no space in front of it

Comment: @Piglet what if a string is 'hello i am hello me is hello are is' and i want to replace the 2nd hello with hola? note that i'm working with player.chatted:connect(msg) events on roblox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to replace a certain occurance of `"hello"` is

```
local text = "hello I am hello I am hello"
local count = 0
local replace = 2
print((text:gsub("hello", function()
  count = count + 1
  if count == replace then
    return "hola"
  end
end)))
```

prints `hello I am hola I am hello`

Alternatively:

```
print(text:gsub("hello", "hola", 2):gsub("hola", "hello", 1))
```

So you replace the first 2 `hello` with `hola` and then the first `hola` with `hello`. This of course only works if there are no other `hola` in that part of the string.